# Can't display image in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Here's my code:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    cout << "This image has " << image.rows <<" rows and "<<image.cols<<" columns"<< endl;
    image = imread("images.jpg");
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Image not read properly" << endl;
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "The size of the image is " << image.rows << " rows and " << image.cols << " columns." << endl;
    cout << "This image has " << image.channels() << " channels." << endl;
    namedWindow("Original_Image",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Original_Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The window which should display the image is just blank. I'm using Visual Studio 2015, OpenCV 3.2.0.

Comment: You start by printing out rows and columns before you have loaded the image. Try again, ensure that image is correctly loaded (has expected dimensions, then print out a few pixels and check they look like real data and not random / uniform).

Answer (score -1):

You might get a blank image if the path of the image is wrong. The blank window is given by the namedWindow statement, which just creates the window. Try giving the full path of the image in imread(eg if your image is saved under Downloads, use the file path as "C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\image.jpg"). Be sure to use double back slashes while specifying the file path(forward slash in linux based systems and back slash in windows!!).